# How do I time travel?

Tags: burrito-bison-launcha

There are two abilities related to time travel in a recent update to Burrito Bison. Their descriptions read:

1. Time travel to unlock this upgrade
2. Reach rift level 18 then time travel to unlock

[image: Locked time travel abilities]

How do I time travel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to a tweet by juicybeast](https://mobile.twitter.com/juicybeast/status/812697247272103937), it is bugged, don't worry about it until the next update:

> **Coelasquid**
>
> Part of me is wondering if you unlock this by resetting your save data... @juicybeast please stop me from making a terrible mistake
>
> **Juicy Beast**
>
> @Coelasquid Don't! Working a patch for this asap. Just ignore it until then ;)

Comment: Ah great. Ok, this is accepted until the patch lands. Thanks. You should edit your answer to include the text of the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

When you're playing (jumping) you will notice in the right lower corner a small purple rift icon and a number. Mine showed rift x11. That means I broke into the deep space 11 times. Rift level 18 basically means you have to break through the cookie crust into space 18 times. A lot of work..

Comment: But how do I time travel? I just cleared another deep space and got a recipe share and the ability requiring time travel did. It unlock.

Answer (score 0):

Once you break past the cake wall in candy land 5 times, you can use the purple button on the top right corner of the shop to time travel. If you break past the cake wall 18 total times and then time travel, you will get the other upgrade

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have to get your character to travel at a certain speed to time travel. I don't however know what this speed is and when you launch with all upgrades and the taco buddy you start at 550 so I would assume you have to hit 600 or faster but this is impossible since it's so hard to build up speed over 400 since half of the options slow you down when you use them over 450. My guess is that these were put on here to encourage people to hit rift 18 and keep playing while they finish updating whatever they will do to allow you to travel faster than 400 without slowing down